# compare 2 columns and if one equal NA, use the other to update it

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, na

I have a data frame looking like so:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
hm_variant_id           x    y
<chr>                <dbl> <dbl>        
1 10_64249655_C_T   0.0749 NA           
2 10_92361338_T_C  -0.0346 NA           
3 10_5224192_T_C   -0.0683 NA           
4 10_25993366_G_C   0.0231 NA           
5 10_20364_A_G      NA    1.9           
6 10_20665_TAAAC_T  0.0202 NA           
7 10_22591_G_T      NA    0.8           
8 10_23187_G_A     -0.250  NA
```

I would like to loop through my data and compare the x and y and update each other in a a way that:

```
if x = NA, then x = log(y)
if y = NA, then y = exp(x)
```

My attempts have been:

```
test2 <- test %>% mutate(new_or = exp(hm_beta))
```

But this creates a new column and does not truly compare x and y.

```
test <- as.data.frame(test)

 calculate <- function(data) {

   x <- as.numeric(data["x"])
   y <- as.numeric(data["y"])

   if (is.na(x) == TRUE){
    x <- log(y)
   }

  if (is.na(y) == TRUE){
   y <- exp(x)
  }
 }

But I get this error:

Error in calculate_beta_ors(test) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

What is the cleanest way to proceed here? Ideally with tidyverse but either way is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple `ifelse` :

```
transform(df, x = ifelse(is.na(x), log(y), x), 
              y = ifelse(is.na(y), exp(x), y))
```

This can be similarly written with `dplyr` functions as well :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(x = if_else(is.na(x), log(y), x), 
         y = if_else(is.na(y), exp(x), y))

#     hm_variant_id      x    y
#1  10_64249655_C_T  0.075 1.08
#2  10_92361338_T_C -0.035 0.97
#3   10_5224192_T_C -0.068 0.93
#4  10_25993366_G_C  0.023 1.02
#5     10_20364_A_G  0.642 1.90
#6 10_20665_TAAAC_T  0.020 1.02
#7     10_22591_G_T -0.223 0.80
#8     10_23187_G_A -0.250 0.78
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(hm_variant_id = c("10_64249655_C_T", "10_92361338_T_C", 
"10_5224192_T_C", "10_25993366_G_C", "10_20364_A_G", "10_20665_TAAAC_T", 
"10_22591_G_T", "10_23187_G_A"), x = c(0.0749, -0.0346, -0.0683, 
0.0231, NA, 0.0202, NA, -0.25), y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.9, NA, 
0.8, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Using *ifelse*:

```
df$new_or <- ifelse(is.na(df$x) & !is.na(df$y), log(df$y),
                    ifelse(is.na(df$y) & !is.na(df$x), exp(df$x), NA))

df
#      hm_variant_id       x   y     new_or
# 1  10_64249655_C_T  0.0749  NA  1.0777764
# 2  10_92361338_T_C -0.0346  NA  0.9659917
# 3   10_5224192_T_C -0.0683  NA  0.9339802
# 4  10_25993366_G_C  0.0231  NA  1.0233689
# 5     10_20364_A_G      NA 1.9  0.6418539
# 6 10_20665_TAAAC_T  0.0202  NA  1.0204054
# 7     10_22591_G_T      NA 0.8 -0.2231436
# 8     10_23187_G_A -0.2500  NA  0.7788008
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(x = case_when(is.na(x) ~ log(y), TRUE  ~ x), 
             y = case_when(is.na(y) ~ exp(x), TRUE ~ y))
```